# error al compilar

Tags: c++, funciones, loops, compilador

Me sale un error al compilar varios ficheros, estos son los errores:

> 93 20      [Error] request for member 'get_aceptacion' in '((nfa*)this)->nfa::estados_.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(((std::vector::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'int'
>
> 94 20      [Error] request for member 'n_transiciones' in '((nfa*)this)->nfa::estados_.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(((std::vector::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'int'
>
> 95 23      [Error] request for member 'get_transiciones' in '((nfa*)this)->nfa::estados_.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(((std::vector::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'int'
>
> 99 8       [Error] no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'std::set::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator}')

Refiriéndose a las siguientes líneas de código:

```
os<<estados_[i].get_aceptacion();//PRIMER ERROR
            os<<estados_[i].n_transiciones();//Segundo error
            for(it=estados_[i].get_transiciones().begin();it!=estados_[i].get_transiciones().end(); it++){ //Aqui se queja de lo mismo por get_transiciones
                os<<it->first;
                for(ik= (*it).second.begin(); ik!=(*it).second.end() ; ik++){ 

                    os<<ik;//CUARTO ERROR
```

Código completo:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>

#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<set>
#include "NFA.hpp"
#include"estadoNFA.cpp"
using namespace std;


    nfa::nfa(){

    }


    void nfa::leernfa(string nombrefichero){
        ifstream F(nombrefichero.c_str());
        bool errorapertura;
        if(F==NULL){
            errorapertura_=true;
            cout<<"No se puede leer el fichero  "<<endl;
        }
        else{
            errorapertura=false;
            int camino;
            estado objeto;
            int identificador;
            char simbolo;

            //map<char,int> transiciones;
            bool aceptacion;

            int n_transiciones;

            int estadosiguiente;
            F>>nestados_>>estadoarranque_;
            //Recuerda que desde un estado puede haber varias transiciones
            set<int> variosestados;
            map<char,set<int> >::iterator it;

            for(int i=0;i<nestados_;i++){ //a 1 a 3 b 2 a 4
                F>>identificador>>aceptacion>>n_transiciones;

                for(int j=0;j<n_transiciones;j++){

                    F>>simbolo>>estadosiguiente;


                    it=objeto.buscar(simbolo);      //varioestados en el if daba problemas, repasa a 1 a 3 b 2 a 4

                    if(it!=objeto.get_transiciones().end()){ 

                        (*it).second.insert(estadosiguiente); //(*posicion) es un puntero, para coger el valor haces asterisco, contiene el tipo de dato que tu tengas en esa memoria solo puedo meter los estadossiguientes correspondientes a un mismo char

                    }
                    else{
                        variosestados.clear(); //podrias crear variosestados aqui y te evitas variosestados.clear()   
                        variosestados.insert(estadosiguiente);  //con esto machacas las a en el if

                        pair<char,set<int> > par2(simbolo,variosestados);
                        objeto.insertar(par2); //no hace falta tener un map del estado actual
                    }
                }
                //estados_.push_back(objeto);

            }
        }
    }
    //aceptacion se relacionara con el booleano acep_ del nfa,identificador con pos, aceptacion con acep_,n_transiciones con trans

    ostream& nfa:: mostrar(ostream& os){
        os<<nestados_<<endl;
        os<<estadoarranque_;
        map<char,set<int> >::iterator it;
        set<int>::iterator ik;
        for(int i=0; i<nestados_;i++){
            os<<i;
            os<<estados_[i].get_aceptacion();
            os<<estados_[i].n_transiciones();
            for(it=estados_[i].get_transiciones().begin(); it!=estados_[i].get_transiciones().end(); it++){
                os<<it->first;
                for(ik= (*it).second.begin(); ik!=(*it).second.end() ; ik++){ //vectorestados[i].get_transiciones().second.end() eso  no, porque cada posicion del map tiene un second, pero el trans_,lo que te devuelve get_transicion, es un conjunto, no tiene second

                    os<<ik;
                }
            }
        }

        return os;
    }
```

La clase estado donde desarrollo las funciones `get_aceptacion()` y mas funciones

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<string>

#include"estadoNFA.hpp"

using namespace std;

//Aqui lo relativo a la informacion que necesitas de cada estado: las transiciones, la posicion del estado, y si es de aceptacion o no para saber donde acaba la lectura


    void estado::insertar(pair<char,set<int> > par){
        trans_.insert(par);
    }

    bool estado::get_aceptacion(void){
        acep_?1:0;
        return acep_;
    }
    map<char,set<int> >::iterator estado:: buscar(char simbolo){ //find devuelve la posicion
        map<char,set<int> >::iterator posicion= trans_.find(simbolo); // find devuelve la posicion,un iterator, por eso map<char,int>::iterator posicion

        return posicion;
    }

    int estado::n_transiciones(void){
        int longitud;
        longitud = trans_.begin()->second.size();
        return longitud;
    }
    map<char,set<int> > estado:: get_transiciones(void){
        return trans_;
    }
    int estado::get_transciones_size(void){
        return trans_.size();
    }
    int estado::get_pos(void){
        return pos_;
    }
    set<int> estado::estadosiguiente(char symbol){
        return (*trans_.find(symbol)).second; 
    }
```

Comment: este codigo seria mucho mas corto y facil de leer si usaras C++ moderno, considera usar `auto` para los iteradores, te facilitan estos errores.

Comment: El último error es fácil: `ik` es un `iterator`, que se comporta como si fuera un puntero. Tienes que *desreferenciarlo* ( `os << *ik` ) para mostrar *aquello a lo que apunta*.

Comment: El resto ... no lo indicas, pero `estados_` es un `std::vector< int >`. ¿ Que es lo que se supone que quieres hacer ? Es normal que no te deje llamar a funciones-miembro en un `int`: no las tiene :-)